# jquery: Run a function after windows load or after a specified time

Tags: jquery

I want to run a function after windows load, but at the same time, it shouldn't take more than 6 seconds. In other words, it should be runed after windows load or after 6 seconds, whichever comes first. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y = 0;

function x() {
    alert('hi');
    y++;
}
func_x = setTimeout(x, 6000);
$(window).load(function () {
    if (y === 0) {
        clearTimeout(func_x);
        x();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you're looking for.

```
function doSomething() {
    // do something
}

var timeout = setTimeout(doSomething, 6000);

$(window).load(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    doSomething();
});
```

Comment: True, and it's a simple fix to unbind the `$(window).load()` if the timeout runs first. The better fix would be to speed up load times.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

and

```
setTimeout()
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Edit: I didn't see that you requested this in jQuery. Here is a link to an example: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function decorator that allows a function that only runs once.

```
function DoOnce(what){
    var done = false, args = arguments.slice(1);

    return function(){
        if (!done) {
            done = true;
            what.apply(args);
        }
    };
}
```

You can then use this, like so:

```
var handler = DoOnce(function(a){ alert(a);}, 1);
window.onload = handler;
setTimeout(handler, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
function yourfunction(){
    //your code
}
var a = setTimeout( yourfunction, 6000);
window.onload = function(){
    if(a){ 
        clearTimeout(a); 
    }else{
        yourfunction();
    }
}
```